# Cannot go to next page on phone but can on computer

Tags: customization

Right now I have 2 pages of info.  If you look up my site on a phone, it says 1 of 2 but you cant click on it to get to 2 . It works if you use a computer tho??  How do I fix this?

Comment: Hello Janeen! Without seeing your site, your code, any error messages in the browser dev console, or your theme, it's not possible to answer this. Questions need to be self contained, and keep in mind this isn't a general support forum, but a developer Q&A site. Please edit your question with as much information as possible, it might be that you need to contact the theme author

Comment: Thank you Tom..I think I need to look elsewhere then.  Being that I am a newbie and do not understand alot.